# What is the difference between Object and Context in Linq/Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, objectcontext

What's the difference between entity object and entity context for auto generated code from database?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I get your question correctly.

**Entity Objects** are the instances of the entity classes which are mapped to the tables of your database (if they are generated automatically).

The **Object Context** (is this what you meant? it is sometimes called entity context as well) is the central class of your EDM (Entity Data Model) with which you query and update the data stored in the DB. By default, it is automatically generated too.

If this is not what you are looking for, please provide more details or be more specific in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Fad,

In an EF-based application a context is responsible for tracking changes that are made to the entities after they have been loaded from the database. You then use the SaveChanges method on the context to persist the changes back to the database

Hope that gave you some idea what context is.